# Freemarker template parallel processing

Tags: freemarker

I have a freemarker template to generate xml from pojo.during this conversion i need to populate some extra datas also to template.if template processing is sequential,so the execution time will be higher.So is it possible to execute some parts of template generation asunchronously or invoking some api's asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

There's no feature for parallelizing the execution of a single template.